# Pandas: complex transformation of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame similar to this one:

```
    player  unit    stat1   stat2
0   p1      u1      10      8
1   p1      u2      21      2
3   p2      u1      2       7
4   p2      u2      32      34
```

One row exists for each combination of player and unit. I would like to transform this DataFrame into one looking like this:

```
            p1      p2
u1  stat1   10      2
    stat2   8       7
u2  stat1   21      32
    stat2   2       34
```

where units and the various stats are turned into a multi-level index and players are turned into columns. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['player'], columns=['unit']).T.swaplevel(0, 1, 0).sort_index()`

Comment: `df.melt(['player', 'unit']).pivot_table('value', ['unit', 'variable'], 'player')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.pivot(index='unit', columns='player').stack(level=0)
```

or without pivot:

```
df.set_index(['unit','player']).stack().unstack('player')
```

Output:

```
player      p1  p2
unit              
u1   stat1  10   2
     stat2   8   7
u2   stat1  21  32
     stat2   2  34
```